# Why Math.pow faster then cached Math.pow (var pow = Math.pow)

Tags: javascript, performance, math, pow

I [made a small test on jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/bt4r9-test-pow).

Why is a simple `Math.pow` faster then cached `Math.pow (var pow = Math.pow)`?

Comment: Some lookups are cheaper than others.

Comment: The compiler may be optimizing the built-in function.

Comment: For me (Firefox 23) the cached one is even faster.

Comment: It seems like FF is same perfomance. But in Chrome simple Math.pow faster. As Barmar said, built-in function my be optimized.

Answer (score 2):

For correct comparison remove

```
var pow = Math.pow;
```

from the test loop and place it in the preparation code.

See http://jsperf.com/bt4r9-test-pow/2

Comment: This is probably better posted as a comment rather than an answer. (It being your first post, though, I won't flag or downvote.)

Comment: This actually makes sense. +1.